# Get more than 100 results from a Facebook graph response with Python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I'm having fun with the FB Graph API collecting "reactions" until I hit the FB limit of 100. (Some of the posts I need to query have well over 1000 reactions) 
I do see dictionary key "next" in the json response which is a link to the next group and that group has a next key and so on. Below is a simplified version of what I have so far...

```
post_id_list = ['387990201279405_1155752427836508'] #short list for this example

def make_post_reaction_url_list(postid_list, APP_ID, APP_SECRET):
''' constructs a list of FB urls to gather reactions to posts limit set to 3'''
    post_id_list_queries = []
    for post_id in postid_list:
       post_id_list_queries.append("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/"+post_id+"?fields=reactions.limit(3)&access_token="+ APP_ID + "|" + APP_SECRET)

    return post_id_list_queries

post_id_reaction_query_list = make_post_reaction_url_list(post_id_list, APP_ID, APP_SECRET)

def return_json_from_fb_query(post_id_rection_query_list):
    list_o_json = []
    for target in post_id_reaction_query_list:
        t = requests.get(target)
        t_json = t.json()
        list_o_json.append(t_json)

    return list_o_json

list_o_json = return_json_from_fb_query(post_id_reaction_query_list)

list_o_json[0]['reactions']['data'] #gives me information for the response 
list_o_json[0]['reactions']['paging']['next'] #returns a http link to the next set of reactions.
```

Any suggestions how I can collect then follow the "next" link, collect info then follow the next link etc. to the end of the node?

Comment: I suppose the last next should be empty?

Comment: My guess is the last next won't have the "next" key... the json response on a query.limit(100) on a postid with less than 100  reactions....   list_o_json[0]['reactions']['paging']['next']
KeyError: 'next'

Comment: So, you should iterate over every response with while statement and as a condition check if there any next key at response

Comment: Thanks @Viacheslav!   that suggestion put me back on track.  I will mark  accepted  if you enter it as an answer.

Comment: should also credit @alanwill  with is git share:   https://github.com/alanwill/python-learning/blob/master/beautifulsoup-follow-links.py